# Wrap each word in string with span using regular exp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

how to replace each word in text with "span" using regular exp?

```
var text = "1:393 1:838 3:936 1:998 1:1398 1:1652 1:1718 1:1806"

final op = "<span class="word">1:393</span><span class="word">1:838</span><span class="word">3:936</span><span class="word">1:998</span><span class="word">1:139</span>...."
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need a regex for that if the separator is always a single space, just split on the space *(or `\b` if you want a regex)*, add some markup, and join back together again.

```js
var text = "1:393 1:838 3:936 1:998 1:1398 1:1652 1:1718 1:1806";

var op = text.split(' ').map(function(w) {
    return '<span class="word">' + w + '------</span>';
}).join('');

document.body.innerHTML = op;
```

```css
.word {color : red}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var op = '<span class="word">' + text.split(' ').join('</span><span class="word">') + '</span>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `String#replace`.

```js
const text = "1:393 1:838 3:936 1:998 1:1398 1:1652 1:1718 1:1806";
const result = text.replace(/\d:\d+/g, '<span class="word">$&</span>');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need (https://jsfiddle.net/6r005vgf/3/):

```
var text = "1:393 1:838 3:936 1:998 1:1398 1:1652 1:1718 1:1806";

//var final = "<span class='word'>1:393</span><span class='word'>1:838</span><span class='word'>3:936</span><span class='word'>1:998</span><span class='word'>1:139</span>....";

var final_test = "<span class='word'>" + text.replace(/\s+/g, "</span><span class='word'>") + "</span>";

//alert(final);
alert(final_test);
```